My program does not accept the AddNewRow as datarow
I have been struggling for days with this one.
My routine does not accept the statement:
dsAddRow = ds.Tables("Nebenkosten").NewRow()

It jumps over it and runs into an error:

Object reference not set to an instance to an object

In the class Header, I have done all the necessary declarations:
Public con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection  
Public dbProvider As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
Public myAppDir = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") 
Public myDatabase As String = myAppDir & "\NebenkostenFuchs.mdb"  
Public ds As New DataSet 
Public da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

In the button_Save routine, I have this code:
'Open the Database       
con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & "Data Source = " & myDatabase         
con.Open()  
  
'******************************************************************          
Try  
   Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)  
       
   Dim dsAddRow As DataRow                      '\<-- It jumps over this statement ?  
   dsAddRow = ds.Tables("Nebenkosten").NewRow() '\<-- and goes in error here?  

   dsAddRow.Item(1) = cmbObjekt.SelectedItem          
   dsAddRow.Item(2) = cmbJahr.SelectedItem          
   dsAddRow.Item(3) = cmbGruppe.SelectedItem           
   dsAddRow.Item(4) = cmbArt.SelectedItem           
   dsAddRow.Item(5) = cbUmlage.Checked           
   dsAddRow.Item(6) = txtSatz.Text           
   dsAddRow.Item(7) = txtBrutto.Text          
   dsAddRow.Item(8) = txtNetto.Text           
   dsAddRow.Item(9) = txtMwSt.Text      
     
   ds.Tables("Nebenkosten").Rows.Add(dsAddRow)          
   da.Update(ds, "Nebenkosten")         `  

   con.Close()          
Catch ex As Exception         `  
   MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString, MessageBoxIcon.Error, "Oops - Fehler")           
   con.Close()           
   Exit Sub          
End Try

In the *.mdb file, I have a table Nebenkosten with an ID column as index (.Item(0))
I can not figure out what is wrong/missing. What am I doing wrong?

The following may be of interest: Retrieving and Modifying Data in ADO.NET and Adding a DataTable to a DataSet

That error message means that there is no DataTable in your DataSet with the name "Nebenkosten", so you have apparently never added one. Where exactly do you think you did so? The fact that such a table exists in the database doesn't mean that it will automatically appear in your DataSet. You have to add it, either by createing a DataTable with that name and adding it directly, or else calling Fill or FillSchema on an appropriate data adaptrer and specifying that table name.

Same goes for da.

"It jumps over this statement". Because that statement doesn't actually do anything besides declare a variable. It's poor practice to declare a variable on one line and then set it on the next. That line and the following line should be combined, i.e. declare and initialise the variable in one line. You're already doing that on the line immediately about. Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da) is shorthand for Dim cb As OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da) but you're not doing that in two lines.

First of all, if you don't need an array of tables (dataset), then don't use one, and use a DataTable. For the vast majority of such cases, then using a DataSet does not make sense, and is not required, nor does such a choice reflect the developer intentions that you only have one table, and Dataset means you intend to load many tables.
Also, you need to "load" the database schema. Now, no one going to suggest you "create" by hand coding each time the columns in the database.
So, easiest approach is to using a query that returns no rows, and I usually use the PK column = 0 for this.
So, this means:
We need a connection.
A data adaptor.   
A SQL command builder

So, the code can be this:
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        conn.Open()

        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = 0"

        Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)

            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            da.Fill(rstData)

            Dim daU As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

            Dim MyNewRow = rstData.NewRow
            MyNewRow("HotelName") = "Test Hotel ZZZ"
            MyNewRow("Active") = True
            MyNewRow("Cost") = 0
            rstData.Rows.Add(MyNewRow)
            da.Update(rstData)

        End Using

    End Using

Note the fill command, we need that to "load/get" the columns from the database.
So, taking above, then your code should look much like this:
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        conn.Open()

        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT * FROM Nebenkosten WHERE ID = 0"

        Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)

            Try
                Dim MyTable As New DataTable
                da.Fill(MyTable)

                Dim daU As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

                Dim dsAddRow = MyTable.NewRow
                dsAddRow.Item(1) = cmbObjekt.SelectedItem
                dsAddRow.Item(2) = cmbJahr.SelectedItem
                dsAddRow.Item(3) = cmbGruppe.SelectedItem
                dsAddRow.Item(4) = cmbArt.SelectedItem
                dsAddRow.Item(5) = cbUmlage.Checked
                dsAddRow.Item(6) = txtSatz.Text
                dsAddRow.Item(7) = txtBrutto.Text
                dsAddRow.Item(8) = txtNetto.Text
                dsAddRow.Item(9) = txtMwSt.Text

                MyTable.Rows.Add(dsAddRow)
                da.Update(MyTable)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString, MessageBoxIcon.Error, "Oops - Fehler")
            End Try

        End Using
    End Using

Note close how we do not (and should not) close the database connection due to the using block.
